# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{{k^2}\binom{n}{k}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I suck in calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{{k^2}\binom{n}{k}}$. It seems it converges to zero.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Sure. Let $a_k(n) = \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{{n \choose k}} 1_{1 \le k \le n}$. Then $|a_k(n)| \le 1$ so $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k(n)}{k^2}$ converges uniformly in $n$. Finally $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_k(n) \to 0$

Answer (score 1):

The dominated convergence with respect to the counting measure on $\mathbb N\setminus{\{0\}}$ fits the bill.

Let $A_n=\{1,\ldots, n\}$ and $\nu$ be the counting measure on $\mathbb N\setminus{\{0\}}$.

Define $\displaystyle f_n: \mathbb N\setminus{\{0\}}\to \mathbb R, k\mapsto \frac{(-1)^{k-1} \mathbb 1_{A_n}(k)}{k^2\binom{n}k}$. For fixed $k\geq 1$, 
$\binom{n}k$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $k$ so that  $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1} \mathbb 1_{A_n}(k)}{k^2\binom{n}k}=0$. This means $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$.

Lastly, $\left|f_n(k) \right| \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$ and $\int \frac{1}{k^2} d\nu(k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}<\infty$.

The dominated convergence theorem applies and yields $\lim_n\int f_n(k) d\nu(k)=0$, that is to say $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{{k^2}\binom{n}{k}}=0$.